# how to add ( admob ) Interstitial ads to libgdx game and what activity to use?

Tags: libgdx, admob

I followed google guide:

1. updated  build.gradle dependencies
2. updated AndroidManifest.xml
3. updated the AndroidLauncher and tried banner ads first
   from libgdx wiki https://libgdx.com/wiki/third-party/admob-in-libgdx

```
@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Create the layout
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

// Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

// Create the libGDX View
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
View gameView = initializeForView(new mygame(), config);

// Create and setup the AdMob view

AdView adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"); // Put in your secret key here

AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Add the libGDX view
layout.addView(gameView);

// Add the AdMob view
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams =
new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

layout.addView(adView, adParams);

// Hook it all up
setContentView(layout);
}}
```

but I cant figure out how to do the same for Interstitial ads

i tried adding adscontroller interface

```
public interface AdsController {
    public void loadInterstitialAd();
    public void showInterstitialAd();
}
```

and updating AndroidLauncher

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AdsController  {



    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private static final String TAG = "Androidlauncher";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // // Create the layout
       RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
                // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create the libGDX View
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView = initializeForView(new mygame(this), config);
        layout.addView(gameView);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });

        AdRequest adRequest = null;
        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

        mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onAdClicked() {
                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was clicked.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when ad is dismissed.
                // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.");
                mInterstitialAd = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                // Called when ad fails to show.
                Log.e(TAG, "Ad failed to show fullscreen content.");
                mInterstitialAd = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdImpression() {
                // Called when an impression is recorded for an ad.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad recorded an impression.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when ad is shown.
                Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.");
            }

        });
        loadInterstitialAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void loadInterstitialAd() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    }

    @Override
    public void showInterstitialAd() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mInterstitialAd!=null) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }
                else loadInterstitialAd();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

InterstitialAd.show(MyActivity.this); require activity but libgdx doesn't work like that(I think?)
every code I found is no longer useful because google updated Admob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidApplication extends Activity, so for interstitials you can just pass in a reference to the application, eg `InterstitialAd.show(this);`

I did something very similar to get interstitials working in my project. I use Ironsource but the process should be very similar. First, I defined an AdManager interface:

```
public interface AdManager {

    /**
     * Show a rewarded video ad
     */
    void showRewardedVideo();

    /**
     * Called on app pause
     */
    void onPause();

    /**
     * Called on app resume
     */
    void onResume();

    /**
     * Attempts to show an interstitial ad
     *
     * @param onSuccess
     * @param onFailed
     */
    void showInterstitial(Listener onSuccess, Listener onFailed);

    /**
     * Called every frame, for any extra work that might need to be done
     *
     * @param deltaTime
     */
    void update(float deltaTime);
}
```

Following that, you can implement your platform's ad provider:

```
public class AndroidAdManager implements AdManager, RewardedVideoListener, InterstitialListener, OfferwallListener {


    private OnlineRPG game;
    private boolean videoAvailable;

    private Listener onInterstitialSuccess;
    private Listener onInterstitialFailed;

    private float timeSinceAd;

    public AndroidAdManager(Activity activity, Gamegame) {
        this.game = game;
        this.activity = activity;

        IronSource.setRewardedVideoListener(this);
        IronSource.setInterstitialListener(this);
        IronSource.setOfferwallListener(this);
        IronSource.init(activity, "whatever");
        IronSource.shouldTrackNetworkState(activity, true);
        IronSource.loadInterstitial();
        IntegrationHelper.validateIntegration(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void showRewardedVideo() {
        if (IronSource.isRewardedVideoPlacementCapped(REWARDED_VIDEO_PLACEMENT_NAME)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Rewarded video placement is capped");
            return;
        }
        IronSource.showRewardedVideo(REWARDED_VIDEO_PLACEMENT_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        IronSource.onPause(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        IronSource.onResume(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void showInterstitial(Listener onSuccess, Listener onFailed) {
        if (timeSinceAd < INTERSTITIAL_MIN_PERIOD || true) {
            onFailed.invoke();
            return;
        }
        this.onInterstitialSuccess = onSuccess;
        this.onInterstitialFailed = onFailed;
        IronSource.showInterstitial(INTERSTITIAL_PLACEMENT_NAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        timeSinceAd += deltaTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAvailabilityChanged(boolean b) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRewardedVideoAvailabilityChanged: " + b);
        videoAvailable = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdStarted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdEnded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdRewarded(Placement placement) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdShowFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClicked(Placement placement) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdReady() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdLoadFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {
        if (onInterstitialFailed != null) {
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onInterstitialFailed.invoke();
                    onInterstitialFailed = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdOpened() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Interstitial Ad Opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdClosed() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Interstitial Ad Closed");
        if (onInterstitialSuccess != null) {
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeSinceAd = 0;
                    onInterstitialSuccess.invoke();
                    onInterstitialSuccess = null;
                }
            });
        }
        IronSource.loadInterstitial();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdShowSucceeded() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdShowFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {
        Log.e(TAG, ironSourceError.getErrorMessage());
        if (onInterstitialFailed != null) {
            Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onInterstitialFailed.invoke();
                    onInterstitialFailed = null;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialAdClicked() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOfferwallAvailable(boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOfferwallOpened() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOfferwallShowFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOfferwallAdCredited(int i, int i1, boolean b) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGetOfferwallCreditsFailed(IronSourceError ironSourceError) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOfferwallClosed() {

    }
}
```

Lastly, in your AndroidLauncher you can create your AndroidAdManager, giving it a reference to your game/activity.

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    private Game game;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        game = new Game();
        game.setAdManager(new AndroidAdManager(this, game));
        game.setPermissionManager(new AndroidPermissionManager(this, game));
        initialize(game, config);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        game.getAds().onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        game.getAds().onResume();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps in your project!

Comment: thank you for your time . i used AndroidLauncher.this as activity in case anyone still looking for an answer .